# Simple post to Facebook page from flash using querystring

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook

Hi
Can someone point me to a simple example of posting to a user's facebook pages using a query string?
ie I'm not using facebook connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to be able to post to a user's facebook page would be to use [Facebook's Share Button](http://www.facebook.com/share/), its super simple to use by just passing the current url ( if your using something like [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) then you could even deeplink them to your applications current section) by replacing the URL params to point u=[your website] & the t=[message to share].

Also to include a picture next to the shared message you will need to look in to [Facebooks's Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph), with a focus on making sure you include the og:image meta property on the base url of your site, which will then show up next to your share content that you posted from flash.

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yourwebsite.com/squareimage.jpg">
```